# Downloading Windows Updates from WSUS server

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

My goal:
A client PC (Windows 10 Pro) automatically downloads Windows Updates from WSUS server and installs them, using Powershell.

My situation:
The client PC has joined an AD domain, and a GPO which designates WSUS server's IP address (http://192.168.1.200:8530) is applied to the PC.

My Problem:
I created the following Powershell script, and run it as Administrator on the PC.

```
# 1. Start Windows Update session
$updateSession = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.Session

# 2. Search Windows Updates
$searcher = $updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$searchResult = $searcher.search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='software'")

# 3. Show the result of Windows Updates
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Downloadable Windows Updates are as follows:"
$searchResult.Updates | % { $_.title -replace ".*(KB\d+).*", "`$1`t$&" }

# 4. Show the result of Windows Updates which are automatically downloadable
$updatesToDownload = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$searchResult.Updates | ? { -not $_.InstallationBehavior.CanRequestUserInput } | ? { $_.EulaAccepted } | % { [void]$updatesToDownload.add($_) }

# 5. Download
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Downloading updates..."
$downloader = $updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
$downloader.Updates = $updatesToDownload
$downloader.Download()

# 6. Show the result of the downloaded updates
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Download is finished."
$updatesToInstall = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$searchResult.Updates | ? { $_.IsDownloaded } | % { [void]$updatesToInstall.add($_) }

# 7. Install
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Installing Updates..."
$installer = $updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$installer.Updates = $updatesToInstall
$installationResult = $installer.Install()

# 8. Show the result of installation (ResultCode 2 is success, over 3 is fail.)
$installationResult

# 9. reboot
Restart-Computer
```

The above script seemed working, but it turned out the clients downloaded updates from the Internet (maybe Microsoft Update Site?). In fact, even when I shut down the WSUS server, this script worked. Downloading and installation were successful.

My Question:
Which part of the script is wrong? Or I can't download updates from WSUS using Powershell?

Comment: Yes, you can download updates from WSUS using a PowerShell script. Whether or not it's working depends on your GPO settings. But you don't have to reinvent the wheel since there is a powerful Windwos Update PowerShell Module out there: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc

Comment: Thank you for the information! Unfortunately, the PC cannot import gallery's powershell modules for my customer's policy... so I need to stick with the preset powershell codes...

Comment: If you can write powershell scripts and execute them, then you can copy and paste the content from the script into a new file.

Comment: As you guys mentioned, I downloaded the module and study the codes. I added the following to the script that works like a charm! `$searcher.ServerSelection = 1` Thank you so much!